# Python terminates process with exit code -1073741819

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf

I am trying to read a csv file (~190MB in size) into a pandas dataframe, but I am getting this error. I am running the Pycharm IDE from JetBrains

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

The code I am trying to run is below:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    frame = df()
    frame.from_csv('c:/Nitin/692/Python/CSV/21LIVvTOT_user_geo_Reply.csv', header=True)
    ab = list(frame.columns.values)
    print(ab)
```

Here is an instance from the CSV:

```
createdat   text    coordinates entities    id_str  in_reply_to_user_id_str
Tue Feb 10 18:56:42 +0000 2015  

"RT @RubieDubes: official list of deluded XXXXX: 
Spurs Fans
Kanye West 
Louis van Gaal"     

{'trends': [], 'urls': [], 'user_mentions': [{'id': 65174814, 'name': 'Ruby ?', 'screen_name': 'RubieDubes', 'indices': [3, 14], 'id_str': '65174814'}], 'symbols': [], 'hashtags': []} 

5.65223E+17
```

EDIT: I tried running it using the python console and it resulted in an error: An unhandled win32 exception occurred in python.exe [11640].

Comment: How do you expect the CSV file to be read? (How should the resulting dataframe look like?) The example CSV you give seems like a very unstructured file.

Comment: I took the sample from excel, but I'd like the dataframe columns to be, created at, text, coordinate and, entities

Comment: Hi, I tried it on another csv and it worked fine, but it still wont work on some csvs of this type. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. There were values in the CSV like  that were not being properly read by the parser. I changed the code from

```
frame.from_csv('c:/Nitin/692/Python/CSV/21LIVvTOT_user_geo_Reply.csv', header=True)
```

to

```
data = pandas.read_csv('c:/Nitin/692/Python/CSV/21LIVvTOT_user_geo_Reply.csv', encoding='latin-1', engine='python')
```

Guess the encoding in utf-8 was causing the problem. The code ran when I changed it to 'latin-1. Thank you for your help.

EDIT: I figured that this was caused due to the emojis present in the data.